# Calling a custom function on each node during DFS traversal

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search, traversal

I am wondering what would be the most elegant way to code a DFS traversal that can be adapted to solve different problems (in C++).

I was thinking to pass a function pointer and a `void *` to my function and let the user pass a callback that would be used on every node.

This is what I have:

### traversals.hpp

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<struct Node> NodePtr;
typedef std::vector<NodePtr> NodeVector;

struct Node {
    int id{0};
    NodeVector children;
};

bool NodeIsInVector(NodePtr node, NodeVector node_vector);

void DFS(NodePtr node, void (*callback)(NodePtr, void * userdata)=nullptr, void * userdata=nullptr);
```

### traversals.cpp

```
bool NodeIsInVector(NodePtr node, NodeVector node_vector){
    auto result = std::find(node_vector.begin(), node_vector.end(), node);
    return result != node_vector.end();
}

void DFS(NodePtr node, void (*callback)(NodePtr, void * userdata), void * userdata){
    static NodeVector visited;

    if (!NodeIsInVector(node, visited)) {
        visited.push_back(node);
        if (callback){
            callback(node, userdata);
        }
    }

    for (auto&& n : node->children){
        if (!NodeIsInVector(n, visited)){
            DFS(n, callback, userdata);
        }
    }
}
```

### Driver code

Here the callback just counts the nodes and increments and integer. Assume that root is a Node pointer and that a tree was defined. The tree has 7 nodes, so the value of `count` is expected to be 7 after the traversal.

```
int count = 0;
DFS(root, [](NodePtr node, void * count){ ++*(int*)count; }, (void*) &count);
std::cout << "DFS count: there are " << count << " nodes.\n";
```

But the output is:
 `DFS count: there are 0 nodes.` The callback gets called (verified by outputting to stdout). The problem is that the userdata variable does not get updated.

My questions are:

- Is this a valid approach to achieve what I want? Are there better approaches?
- What would be the error I made?

Comment: A `void(*)(void*)` pointer and `void*` data pair are good for C callbacks, but in C++ I'd usually prefer a `std::function<void()>`. (Or a template parameter when possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but I suspect the problem was due to the `static` variable defined inside DFS.

I omitted to mention in my question that DFS was called with a different callback that did not increment the count variable before being called with the callback that did. I though it was not relevant to my question.

Could having a static variable declared in the function cause the callback function not to be replaced during the second call?

The following version works as expected. I also replaced the function pointer with an `std::function` reflecting some suggestions made in comments but more importantly I created a wrapper that declares the `visited` NodeVector and this allowed me to not have any `static` declarations.

```
void DFS(NodePtr &node, std::function<void(NodePtr)> callback){
    NodeVector visited;
    _DFS(node, callback, visited);
}

void _DFS(NodePtr &node, std::function<void(NodePtr)> callback, NodeVector& visited){
    if (!NodeIsInVector(node, visited)) {
        visited.push_back(node);
        callback(node);
    } else {
        for(auto item : visited){
            std::cout<<item->id << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    for (auto&& n : node->children){
        if (!NodeIsInVector(n, visited)){
            _DFS(n, callback, visited);
        }
    }
}
```

And the driver code:

```
int count = 0;
DFS(root, [&count](NodePtr node) mutable { ++count; });
std::cout << "DFS count: there are " << count << " nodes.\n";
```

Produces:

> DFS count: there are 7 nodes

Note that the same function but with a `static NodeVector visited;` instead of the wrapper strategy does not work as intended. I am still not 100% clear why.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. When your first call `DFS` twice with `static NodeVector visited`, all the nodes from the first call would still remain in `visited`. Thus, your second call to `DFS` that increment counts would immediately return as all the nodes are already in `visited`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is that you return if the node has no children before calling the callback. This would result in only the parent nodes calling the callback.

I would remove the *is children empty* check entirely. If a node has no children, the for loop would not execute.

```cpp
void DFS(NodePtr node, void (*callback)(NodePtr, void * userdata), void * userdata){
    static NodeVector visited;

    if (!NodeIsInVector(node, visited)) {
        visited.push_back(node);
        if (callback){
            callback(node, userdata);
        }
    }

    for (auto&& n : node->children){
        if (!NodeIsInVector(n, visited)){
            DFS(n, callback, userdata);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right that the children empty check is redundant, I removed it from the code. But it does not solve the problem (the result is still "DFS count: there are 0 nodes" after removing it). I will also edit my question to reflect these changes.

Comment: @EmilePapillon-Corbeil could it be an issue with `NodeVector` and `NodeIsInVector`? I tried implementing it visited with an unordered_set<Node*> and it works!

Comment: Interesting that it works on your side. I added my code for NodeVector and NodeIsInVector to my question. I could not find what might be wrong. The traversal itself works like it should: if I make the callback just print the node's ids it works.